# Long running task in javafx service results in flickering update messages in bound elements

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a javfx service which makes some network calls.

```
public class ConnectionChecker extends Service<String> {
    ...

@Override
protected Task<String> createTask() {
    return new Task<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {
            // some expensive message calls here
            updateMessage("connection established");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

at another point I bind the message to a label:

```
headerLabel.textProperty().bind(service.messageProperty());
```

What I can see now is that the label losts its value as long the service is running. The service is called periodically in a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. Does anyone have an idea why the bounded value is empty for time the task is executed?

Answer (score 0):

The default task message is empty. It's bound to service message when service started. So it looks like default empty task message updates label text that way. Did you try to set initial message text to the task in the createTask() method?